# Data annotation to check if within set of values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

When validating `string` properties with data annotation attributes does anyone know of a way to validate the string is one of a set of possible values, perhaps expressed as an array or delimitated string?

The question is more general purpose, but the specific instance I ran into is with a property that can contain a subset of the HTTP methods; specifically, `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH` and `DELETE`.

In the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace I see the `RegularExpressionAttribute` that I could potentially subclass this and dynamically create the RegEx, but wondering if I'm missing something that already exists.

Answer is not restricted to .NET framework.  3rd party libraries and even custom code are both acceptable, but the closer to standard (meaning in this case, well adopted) the better.

Thanks

Comment: Do note that data annotations are *annotations*. They do not, by themselves, validate anything. You'd still need code that actually respects annotations in order for something to happen. This applies to any solution that's not the property setter actually validating the incoming values.

Comment: If a `RegularExpressionAttribute` does not meet your needs, you can create custom validation attributes that implement `IClientVaidatable` that will give you both client and server side validation [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @StephenMuecke -- see my self-answer.  If you change your comment to an answer I will accept it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like inheriting `RegularExpressionAttribute` is the route to take, or to build my own from scratch as Steven Muecke stated in a comment.

As a side note, I ultimately refactored for other reasons and no longer need the annotation.  But that is often the case when I run into issues that don't have obvious and straightforward solutions.

Answer (score 4):

in my code i use like this:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("GET|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE", ErrorMessage = "Only http method allowed.")]
public string method { get; set; }
```

Note: It will not show error message if passed empty string to `method` then i use `[Required]` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**Remote Validation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx) for this purpose:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("Check", "yourModel",
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        ErrorMessage = "Username is not available.")]
public string Name { set; get; }
```

And:

```
public ActionResult Check(string name)
{
     string[] names = {"name1", "name2", "name3"};//set of possible values

     //validate the string is one of a set of possible values
     if (names.Contains(name.ToLowerInvariant())) return Json(false);
     //...
     return Json(true);
}
```

Also you can use [`AdditionalFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.additionalfields(v=vs.118).aspx) to gets or sets the additional fields that are required for validation. `AdditionalFields` property is string property and can be provided for multiple fields.